# Authenticating user with facebook on iOS without UIWebView

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth, ios

Is there a way to authenticate a user with facebook in the background using id/pass he entered in configuration screen? I mean authentication without the usage of UIWebView, but using some kind of Http client to retrieve auth token (OAuth 2.0 preferably)

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth site lists [several options](http://oauth.net/code/) for Objective-C, including [`MPOAuthConnection`](http://code.google.com/p/mpoauthconnection/). You could probably tweak it to use with [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or similar to place a request with credentials.